# Macvlan based interface pings from host but not from namespace

Tags: linux, networking, iproute2, namespaces

[EDIT]

The production system is currently a mix physical and ESXi based system. We obviously would never use virtualbox even for a pre-production environment ! It was used here only to quickly narrow down the problem directly on my desktop.

Thanks for the explanation for the "on hold" on meta !

[/EDIT]

My setup:

1. Private network `vboxnet1` 10.0.7.0/24
2. 1 Host, ubuntu desktop
3. 1 VM, ubuntu server (VirtualBox)

Adressing layout:

1. HOST: 10.0.7.1
2. VM: 10.0.7.101
3. VM *MAC NAMESPACE*: 10.0.7.102

On the `VM`, I ran the following commands:

```
ip netns add mac                        # create a new nmespace
ip link add link eth0 mac0 type macvlan # create a new macvlan interface
ip link set mac0 netns mac
```

On the `mac` namespace, inside the VM:

```
ip link set lo up
ip link set mac up
ip addr add 10.0.7.102/24 dev mac0
```

So that we basically end up with: (Like Inception ?)

```
+------------------------+
| Host: 10.0.7.1         |
|                        |
| +--------------------+ |
| | VM: 10.0.7.101     | |
| |                    | |
| | +----------------+ | |
| | | NS: 10.0.7.102 | | |
| | |                | | |
| | +----------------+ | |
| +--------------------+ |
+------------------------+
```

What works:

- Ping between `Host` and `VM`
- Ping between `NS` and `NS`
- dhclient from `NS`

What does not work:

- ping between `NS` and `VM`
- ping between `NS` and `Host`

Where I started to go nuts:

- tcpdump on `host` (the real machine) actually shows ARP request AND replies
- tcpdump on `NS` shows ARP requests sent to the host
- tcpdump on `VM` makes the whole mess work (!) --> ping starts to get answers when tcpdump is started on the VM ?!?

So, I bet you were eager for it, my question is: how to I make it work ? I suspect something's wrong with ARP on the macvlan inside the NS but can't figure out what exactly...

Btw, I did the same expérimentations with the `mac0` interface directly on the VM (no namespace) and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been flagged as off-topic. It's definitely a sysadmin/netadmin question, relevant to multiple virtualization environments, and it's not a trivial one (or, if it is, 90% of the questions on StackOverflow are off-topic as well). I would love if the people who flagged it as "off-topic" bothered to explain why, rather than copy-pasting a rule that obviously doesn't apply here. Thank you!

Comment: @jpetazzo This isn't off-topic, and I can only assume the people closing did so based on the poor organization/presentation of the question (likely due to the OP not being a sys/net admin). Also, [SF]'s scope (not just topic) is different from [so] - your argument makes me think you haven't visited our [help] as it makes no sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, so, for posterity, the fact that tcpdump makes all suddenly works should have put me on track. What it does internally is switch `eth0` into promiscuous mode. That is to say, `eth0` will yield all the network traffic, not only the one with the server's main `MAC`

However, this is precisely how `macvlan` works: it adds a new secondary virtual MAC address which the "physical" (that's a VM) network adapter doesn't know.

So the easy workaround is to manually: `ifconfig eth0 promisc`

I hope it helps !

Comment: So you had to uncheck "no promisc mode" on that VM as well, I suppose?

Comment: Indeed, it is unchecked.